# Error "Load Report Failed" in Crystal Report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-2010

I have developed a demo application of crystal reports. My app works fine on local machine but when published on IIS 7 my page gives error "load report failed". Do I need to do some extra settings on IIS? What should I do? It's not even displaying an empty crystal report viewer. I have just published and ran the app on server? I have not done anything extra.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the server as well, Crystal Report is ran properly.
On your machine that was done (looks like), but you also need to run set up on server, so that report can be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a simple case of the path to the RPT being different between the development and production machines. Consider this inside your .aspx web form page:

```
    <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
        <Report FileName="~/MyCrystalReport.rpt">
        </Report>
    </CR:CrystalReportSource>
```

When I changed my filename to include a referential path to the report file (in the same folder as my .aspx folder) it started working.